# Opera not loading CSS completely

Tags: css, opera

I have an issue with Opera and CSS. Somehow Opera leaves out the last 5 or so entries in my CSS file, which causes my website not being rendered correctly in Opera. Is it just me (I presume it is), but here is the relevant CSS code:

```
/* Other CSS that works correctly... */

.cell-spacing {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* Everything below this comment is left out in Opera... */

#upload, #install, #delete {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.softwareTable {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#packageSelect {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    min-width: 360px;
}

#output {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#loadingInstall {
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.output-group-header{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? I've validated the CSS, but apart from the `resize: none;` in the `#output` block, that code is valid (resize being a CSS3 property)... Every other browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari & IE) seems to load the CSS correctly.

---

Edit:

I've tried placing the code that get's left out in Opera above the .cell-spacing element, but this actually has no effect whatsoever. It just doesn't get loaded into Opera... >.>"

Comment: Is the CSS file huge, so that you might run into some limitation of the number of rules it can contain? What does the rules look like just before it stops working?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "What does the rules look like just before it stops working"? I inspected the CSS file in Opera, and all the other rules look normal. It just get's clipped below the .cell-spacing element.

Comment: In addition to running through a validator, I'd check CSS lint as it checks for and finds common syntax errors and warns about common cross-browser development issues: http://csslint.net/

Comment: Lint found no errors, just a bunch of warnings. The validator also spat out a bunch of warnings, but nothing to serious though... ;)

Comment: Sadly, no. It is a proprietary site under development. And it's hosted on an internal network with no possibility to expose to the www... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, Opera decided to be a b*tch... It seemed that clearing the mem cache and a restart was all that was needed to correctly load the css for the webpage... *sigh* the wonderous world of webdevelopment...

Answer (score 0):

[Comments in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments) start with `/*` and end with `*/`.  It's possible the other browsers are more loosely enforcing the proper syntax, but looking at your code this seems the most likely culprit.

```
/* comments in CSS look like this */
```

Comment: The comments shown in the example aren't there in the file. It was just my clarification, but I guess it couldn't hurt to be syntactically correct. I'll edit it...